# how to select a value from a second column using a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

If I have a text file with:

```
MachineName    IPAddress
Computer1234   10.0.1.1
Computer1235   10.0.1.2
Computer1236   10.0.1.3
```

Once I grab the MachineName from the computer, how can I get the corresponding IPAddress from the text above?

The (bash?) script will be run on a Mac, and the text above can be reformatted and/or inserted into the script itself (about 110 computers)...

Comment: Possibly awk would be better for this.

Comment: I cannot test it right now but try `awk -v machine=Computer1235 '$1==machine {print $2}' file.txt`

Comment: @sircapsalot not a duplicate of that one because there's a match on the first column using a variable (else it's useless)

Comment: @sircapsalot I don't agree: read the question: "once I get the computer name I want the address".

Comment: you might be right @Jean-FrançoisFabre.  i'll go ahead and leave the comments in just in case, and leave my close vote in.  thanks!

Comment: I am right and someone answered exactly the same thing... you owe me 15 rep :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre :D . considering the OP has 1 rep, and they haven't responded to any comments or answers - i doubt anybody is getting rep today :X

Comment: I'm getting rep on other questions right now. This one is a lost cause :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what awk is made for: search for fields by pattern and then do some action. The basic idea is

```
awk '/pattern/ {action}' file
```

In your case that would be

```
awk '/Computer1234/ { print $2 }' file
```

In fact, you could be more specific, using the general awk use case

```
awk 'condition { action }' file
```

with

```
awk '$1 == "Computer1234" { print $2 }' file
```

On a different note, converting host names to IP addresses is what *name servers* do. If this is more than playing around and needs to scale, you should insert that data into a name server's zone files, then use name service access tools like `dig` to query the address(es) associated with a host name.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the pointer, I keep learning and removed the shell snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Using grep makes it pretty straight forward.

`grep 'Computer1234' text_file.txt | awk '{print $2}'`

However we can do better and just use awk alone.

`awk -v hostname='Computer1234' '$1 ~ hostname {print $2}' text_file.txt`

`-v var_name=` is how you pass awk variables.

`$1 ~ hostname` looks to see if the first field contains a pattern that matches the hostname variable, if it does we print the ip!

Comment: You shouldn't even show the `grep|awk` anti-pattern.

Comment: If your familiar with grep and unfamiliar with awk there's no harm in showing how the two commands are related in my opinion.